# App stuck on the Splash screen in Android 12 (API Level 31)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-api-levels, android-12, android-splashscreen

The application is stuck on the splash screen. No idea why? I have done everything the same as the documentation. Please look at my code and please tell.

Android Manifest.xml file code:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ui.startup.StartupActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xml code

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

app.gradle dependency Code:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

StartUpActivity Code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    installSplashScreen()
 }

 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    proceedNavigation()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://tedblob.com/android-12-splash-screen/), you must call the installSplashScreen function in your main or launcher activity. You must call it before the setContentView.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

You should also consider specifying the activity theme to the attribute postSplashScreenTheme so you can have separate themes for your splash screen and application.

Comment: Issue was in fresco image loading library. Now it works